# My discord bot, doesnt get any videos code

Tags: python, youtube, command, bots, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def buscayt(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'href = "/watch/\?v=(.{11})"', html_content.read().decode())
    print(search_results)
```

When I use the command, in print(search_results), should appear me ["with codes"], but it onlly appears [], without anything

Comment: Are you sure your regex pattern is correct? An empty string means no matches were found.

Comment: @MusabGuma'a, its all correct, because it doesn’t say anything in the console, but I don’t know why